# Have all endpoints in same path and declared ending path inside header

Tags: java, spring, endpoint

I have one endpoint for all app like *https://localhost:8080/test* and inside header I have parameter with rest of URL. Do you know how can make this work in java/spring proyect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map your requests with a specific header with the **headers** parameter of **@RequestMapping**.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/test")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(headers = "X-TEST=1")
    public void path1() {
        // Called when header "X-TEST" present and with 1
    }

    @RequestMapping(headers = "X-TEST=2")
    public void path2() {
        // Called when header "X-TEST" present and with 2
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: But if in header have multiple params and I want to filter just by one? like i have one param for oAuthToken and another are filter to call different method inside TestController

Comment: That will still work, even if there is multiple headers. The method above will map your requests with the "X-TEST" header even if there is more headers than this one. You also can specify multiple headers in an array like `headers = {"X-TEST=1", "oAuthToken"}`.